# Ethers.js ignore revert

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm using Hardhat to deploy my contract locally, and Ethers.js and Node.js run a Javascript file which makes sequential calls to the contract to simulate user activity. When the contract reverts (for example somebody calls the transfer() function with a zero balance) I want Ethers.js to ignore it instead of stopping execution of the Javascript. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: try / catch blocks no good?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as sola24 said in the comments you can use a try and catch block, like this:

```
try {
    //call contract
}catch(error){
   //keep working on javascript code
}
```

More info about try/catch blocks [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Also you could use openzepelin's test helpers, `expectRevert` to be precise, just install it via npm:

```
npm install --save-dev @openzeppelin/test-helpers
```

remember to import `@openzeppelin/test-helpers` on your test file and create a test as follows:

```
it('reverts when transferring tokens you dont have', async function () {
    // Conditions that trigger a require statement can be precisely tested
    await expectRevert(
      this.erc20.transfer(some_address, 5000, { from: sender }),
      'Not enough funds',
    );
  });
```

More info about it on their [readme](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers).